# How to remove whitespace in between character strings

Tags: r, string, character, removing-whitespace

I am trying to clean a .txt file and need to remove white spaces **between** the character strings (totaling 132).
I created breaks for each document by using the pattern

```r
pagepattern <- '\\d+ of \\d\\d\\d DOCUMENTS'
text.split <- as.character(str_split(text,pagepattern))
```

There is no gap at the very beginning or in-between strings 131 and 132, but there is a huge white space gap between all other strings.

```
> I didn`t even have to say it. Just pointing out the irony.\r\n\r\nMy thanks to Kate Zernike of \"The New York Times\", Evan McMorris-Santoro with\r\nBuzzFeed, Krystal Ball with MSNBC.com, Republican consultant Adolfo Franco --\r\nthank you very much.\r\n\r\nAnd to you for getting UP for us tonight.\r\n\r\nUp next, \"MELISSA HARRIS-PERRY\". Stay tuned. Don`t miss that.\r\n\r\nTHIS IS A RUSH TRANSCRIPT. THIS COPY MAY NOT BE IN ITS FINAL FORM AND MAY BE\r\nUPDATED.\r\n\r\nLOAD-DATE: March 2, 2015\r\n\r\nLANGUAGE: ENGLISH\r\n\r\nTRANSCRIPT: 022801cb.450\r\n\r\nDOCUMENT-TYPE: Show\r\n\r\nPUBLICATION-TYPE: Transcript\r\n\r\n                       Copyright 2015  CQ-Roll Call, Inc.\r\n                              All Rights Reserved\r\n\r\n                             Copyright 2015  MSNBC\r\n\r\n\r\n                              "
[132] "\r\n\r\n\r\n                                     MSNBC\r\n\r\n                           February 28, 2015 Saturday\r\n\r\n                    SHOW: MELISSA HARRIS-PERRY 10:00 AM EST\r\n\r\nMELISSA HARRIS-PERRY for February 28, 2015\r\n\r\nBYLINE: Melissa Harris-Perry\r\n\r\nGUESTS: Fred Azcarate, Nina Turner, Matt Welch, Scot Ross, Lori Adelman, Chloe\r\nAngyal, Crystal Valentine, Leigh Ann Caldwell, Julia Angwin\r\n\r\nSECTION: NEWS; Domestic\r\n\r\nLENGTH: 14829  words\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\"
```

I have tried `str_trim`, `str_replaceall`, `gsub`, and none of it seems to do the trick.
I want to erase the white space in between all the strings like it is in the example above. Thanks!

EDIT: picture included to show what the end of each string looks like
[image]

Comment: How about those line breaks? What codes did you try? `str_replace_all(your_string, "\\s{2,}", " ")`?

Comment: Would `str_squish` help?

Comment: @tauft ```str_squish``` did not help either.

Comment: @MartinGal I have tried the following: ```str_replace_all(text, "\\s{2,}^\\s[[:punct:]]\\s MSNBC", " ")```
```gsub("\\s{2,}^\\s[[:punct:]]\\s MSNBC", "", text)```
  ```gsub("MSNBC \\s[[:punct:]]$\\s{2,}^\\s[[:punct:]]\\s MSNBC", "", text)```
  ```str_trim(text, side = "both")```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example